# How to style my boxes and labels on my website?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to format it so that the question label "q" is centered and located above the question box, and below that also centered is the "A" label and box, with the button below that. Any help is appreciated.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
label,
input {
 width: 120px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
 width: 240px;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 2px;
}
br {
 clear: left;
}
.button {
 width: 120px;
 background: rgba(144, 255, 246, 0.42);
 color: #0000a0;
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 250px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(assets/bg1.png);
}
```

```html
<form name="ThisForm">
    <h1>Learning to multiply</h1>
  
    Q:
    <input type="text" name="question" id="question" disabled="disabled" />A:
    <input type="text" name="Ans" id="Ans" maxlength="3" size="3" />
    <input type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="buttonPressed()"/>
    <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the JavaScript code you provided could be in any way relevant to answer your question? Isn't it a CSS question?

Comment: @gus27 I agree with your observation, that's why I added html and css tags (needs to be peer reviewed for it to show).

Comment: @gus27 sorry im in a rush so i simply ctrl a and pasted sorry, i will remove   everything but the <style> part

Comment: ...and please remove the `javascript` tag from the question and add the tag `css`.

Comment: Leave the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: @Adam Curious why you deleted previous Question after an answer was provided?

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-align` to `center` for `form` element; set `"Q:"` and `"A:"` text as `html` of `span` elements, respectively; remove `float: left` from `css`; set `input` `position` to `relative`; set `form input` `left` to `50%` minus `input` `width` divided by `2` using `calc()` function.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
label,
input {
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  width: 240px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.button {
  width: 120px;
  background: rgba(144, 255, 246, 0.42);
  color: #0000a0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

form {
  text-align:center;
}

form input {
  left: calc(50% - 120px / 2);
}
```

```html
<form name="ThisForm">
  <h1>Learning to multiply</h1>
  <span>Q:</span>
  <input type="text" name="question" id="question" disabled="disabled" />
  <span>A:</span>
  <input type="text" name="Ans" id="Ans" maxlength="3" size="3" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="buttonPressed()" />
</form>
```